# Errors while building vlc-qt from source with QT 5.12.3

Tags: cmake, qt5, libvlc, vlc-qt

i am trying to build vlc-qt from source with the QT5.12.3 (need this specific version)

I tried to use with ninja and mingw makefiles and i get those error and i tried with more then 10 other vlc sdk versions

**Source:**

1. vlc-qt 1.1.1 and 1.2.0  - https://github.com/bibiparrot/vlc-qt
2. vlc 3.0.16  - http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win64/
3. qt 5.12.3  - https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.3/

**Errors with MinGW:** full log (https://pastebin.com/raw/9U9Z9BTt)

```
C:\vlc-qt\build>cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ^  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\vlc-qt\build" ^  -DQt5Core_DIR="C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\lib\cmake\Qt5Core"   -DQt5Quick_DIR="C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\lib\cmake\Qt5Quick"   -DQt5Widgets_DIR="C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\lib\cmake\Qt5Widgets"   -DQt5QuickTest_DIR="C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\lib\cmake\Qt5QuickTest"   -DQt5Test_DIR="C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\lib\cmake\Qt5Test"   -DLIBVLC_LIBRARY="C:\vlc-3.0.16\sdk\lib\libvlc.lib" ^  -DLIBVLCCORE_LIBRARY="C:\vlc-3.0.16\sdk\lib\libvlccore.lib" ^  -DLIBVLC_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\vlc-3.0.16\sdk\include"
-- Building VLC-Qt 1.2.0
-- Git revision: 7616e81
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Build statically: OFF
-- Using Qt 5.12.3
-- Installing to system QML import path: OFF
-- Found LibVLC include-dir path: C:/vlc-3.0.16/sdk/include
-- Found LibVLC library path:C:/vlc-3.0.16/sdk/lib/libvlc.lib
-- Found LibVLCcore library path:C:/vlc-3.0.16/sdk/lib/libvlccore.lib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/vlc-qt/build

C:\vlc-qt\build>mingw32-make
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -SC:\vlc-qt -BC:\vlc-qt\build --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\vlc-qt\build\CMakeFiles C:\vlc-qt\build\\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
mingw32-make  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/vlc-qt/build'
mingw32-make  -f src\core\CMakeFiles\Core_autogen.dir\build.make src/core/CMakeFiles/Core_autogen.dir/depend
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/vlc-qt/build'
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\vlc-qt C:\vlc-qt\src\core C:\vlc-qt\build C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core\CMakeFiles\Core_autogen.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target Core_autogen
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/vlc-qt/build'
mingw32-make  -f src\core\CMakeFiles\Core_autogen.dir\build.make src/core/CMakeFiles/Core_autogen.dir/build
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/vlc-qt/build'
[  1%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target Core
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_autogen C:/vlc-qt/build/src/core/CMakeFiles/Core_autogen.dir/AutogenInfo.json Debug
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/vlc-qt/build'
[  1%] Built target Core_autogen
mingw32-make  -f src\core\CMakeFiles\Core.dir\build.make src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/depend
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/vlc-qt/build'
[  2%] Generating VLCQtCore.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\windres.exe -i C:/vlc-qt/build/src/core/VLCQtCore.rc -o C:/vlc-qt/build/src/core/VLCQtCore.obj
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\vlc-qt C:\vlc-qt\src\core C:\vlc-qt\build C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core\CMakeFiles\Core.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target Core
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/vlc-qt/build'
mingw32-make  -f src\core\CMakeFiles\Core.dir\build.make src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/build
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/vlc-qt/build'
[  3%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Core_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\Core_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core\Core_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp
[  4%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/AbstractVideoFrame.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\AbstractVideoFrame.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\AbstractVideoFrame.cpp
[  5%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/AbstractVideoStream.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\AbstractVideoStream.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\AbstractVideoStream.cpp
[  6%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Audio.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\Audio.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\Audio.cpp
[  7%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Common.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\Common.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\Common.cpp
[  9%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Enums.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\Enums.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\Enums.cpp
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Error.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\Error.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\Error.cpp
[ 11%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Instance.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\Instance.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\Instance.cpp
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Media.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\Media.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\Media.cpp
C:\vlc-qt\src\core\Media.cpp: In static member function 'static void VlcMedia::libvlc_callback(const libvlc_event_t*, void*)':
C:\vlc-qt\src\core\Media.cpp:363:74: warning: 'void VlcMedia::parsedChanged(int)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         emit core->parsedChanged(event->u.media_parsed_changed.new_status);
                                                                          ^
In file included from C:\vlc-qt\src\core\Media.cpp:26:
C:/vlc-qt/src/core/Media.h:321:28: note: declared here
     Q_DECL_DEPRECATED void parsedChanged(int status);
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MediaList.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\MediaList.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\MediaList.cpp
[ 14%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MediaListPlayer.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\MediaListPlayer.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\MediaListPlayer.cpp
[ 15%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MediaPlayer.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\MediaPlayer.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\MediaPlayer.cpp
[ 17%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MetaManager.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\MetaManager.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\MetaManager.cpp
[ 18%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/ModuleDescription.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\ModuleDescription.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\ModuleDescription.cpp
[ 19%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/TrackModel.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\TrackModel.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\TrackModel.cpp
C:\vlc-qt\src\core\TrackModel.cpp: In copy constructor 'VlcTrackModel::VlcTrackModel(const VlcTrackModel&)':
C:\vlc-qt\src\core\TrackModel.cpp:29:1: warning: base class 'class QAbstractListModel' should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor [-Wextra]
 VlcTrackModel::VlcTrackModel(const VlcTrackModel &other)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Video.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\Video.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\Video.cpp
[ 21%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/VideoStream.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\VideoStream.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoStream.cpp
[ 22%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/YUVVideoFrame.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\YUVVideoFrame.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\YUVVideoFrame.cpp
[ 23%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/VideoFrame.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -Wno-deprecated -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\VideoFrame.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoFrame.cpp
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/VideoMemoryStream.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -Wno-deprecated -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\VideoMemoryStream.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoMemoryStream.cpp
C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoMemoryStream.cpp:27:56: warning: 'VlcVideoMemoryStream' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declaration
]
 static inline VlcVideoMemoryStream *p_this(void *opaque) { return static_cast<VlcVideoMemoryStream *>(opaque); }
                                                        ^
In file included from C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoMemoryStream.cpp:25:
C:/vlc-qt/src/core/VideoMemoryStream.h:55:43: note: declared here
 class Q_DECL_DEPRECATED VLCQT_CORE_EXPORT VlcVideoMemoryStream
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoMemoryStream.cpp: In function 'VlcVideoMemoryStream* p_this(void*)':
C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoMemoryStream.cpp:27:100: warning: 'VlcVideoMemoryStream' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 static inline VlcVideoMemoryStream *p_this(void *opaque) { return static_cast<VlcVideoMemoryStream *>(opaque); }
                                                                                                    ^
In file included from C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoMemoryStream.cpp:25:
C:/vlc-qt/src/core/VideoMemoryStream.h:55:43: note: declared here
 class Q_DECL_DEPRECATED VLCQT_CORE_EXPORT VlcVideoMemoryStream
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoMemoryStream.cpp: At global scope:
C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoMemoryStream.cpp:28:57: warning: 'VlcVideoMemoryStream' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declaration
]
 static inline VlcVideoMemoryStream *p_this(void **opaque) { return static_cast<VlcVideoMemoryStream *>(*opaque); }
                                                         ^
In file included from C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoMemoryStream.cpp:25:
C:/vlc-qt/src/core/VideoMemoryStream.h:55:43: note: declared here
 class Q_DECL_DEPRECATED VLCQT_CORE_EXPORT VlcVideoMemoryStream
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoMemoryStream.cpp: In function 'VlcVideoMemoryStream* p_this(void**)':
C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoMemoryStream.cpp:28:101: warning: 'VlcVideoMemoryStream' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 static inline VlcVideoMemoryStream *p_this(void **opaque) { return static_cast<VlcVideoMemoryStream *>(*opaque); }
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from C:\vlc-qt\src\core\VideoMemoryStream.cpp:25:
C:/vlc-qt/src/core/VideoMemoryStream.h:55:43: note: declared here
 class Q_DECL_DEPRECATED VLCQT_CORE_EXPORT VlcVideoMemoryStream
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 26%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Equalizer.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\Equalizer.cpp.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\Equalizer.cpp
[ 27%] Building C object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/compat/asprintf.c.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\gcc.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_C.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\compat\asprintf.c.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\compat\asprintf.c
[ 28%] Building C object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/compat/vasprintf.c.obj
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\gcc.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT @CMakeFiles/Core.dir/includes_C.rsp -g -Wall -Wextra -o CMakeFiles\Core.dir\compat\vasprintf.c.obj -c C:\vlc-qt\src\core\compat\vasprintf.c
[ 29%] Linking CXX shared library libVLCQtCored.dll
cd /d C:\vlc-qt\build\src\core && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\Core.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E rm -f CMakeFiles\Core.dir/objects.a
```

**Errors with ninja:** full log (https://pastebin.com/raw/Fxidf7hi)

```
C:\vlc-qt\build>cmake .. -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ^  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\vlc-qt\build" ^  -DQt5Core_DIR="C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\lib\cmake\Qt5Core"   -DQt5Quick_DIR="C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\lib\cmake\Qt5Quick"   -DQt5Widgets_DIR="C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\lib\cmake\Qt5Widgets"   -DQt5QuickTest_DIR="C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\lib\cmake\Qt5QuickTest"   -DQt5Test_DIR="C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\lib\cmake\Qt5Test"   -DLIBVLC_LIBRARY="C:\vlc-3.0.16\sdk\lib\libvlc.lib" ^  -DLIBVLCCORE_LIBRARY="C:\vlc-3.0.16\sdk\lib\libvlccore.lib" ^  -DLIBVLC_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\vlc-3.0.16\sdk\include"
-- Building VLC-Qt 1.2.0
-- Git revision: 7616e81
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Build statically: OFF
-- Using Qt 5.12.3
-- Installing to system QML import path: OFF
-- Found LibVLC include-dir path: C:/vlc-3.0.16/sdk/include
-- Found LibVLC library path:C:/vlc-3.0.16/sdk/lib/libvlc.lib
-- Found LibVLCcore library path:C:/vlc-3.0.16/sdk/lib/libvlccore.lib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/vlc-qt/build

C:\vlc-qt\build>ninja
[10/88] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/TrackModel.cpp.obj
../src/core/TrackModel.cpp: In copy constructor 'VlcTrackModel::VlcTrackModel(const VlcTrackModel&)':
../src/core/TrackModel.cpp:29:1: warning: base class 'class QAbstractListModel' should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor [-Wextra]
 VlcTrackModel::VlcTrackModel(const VlcTrackModel &other)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[17/88] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Media.cpp.obj
../src/core/Media.cpp: In static member function 'static void VlcMedia::libvlc_callback(const libvlc_event_t*, void*)':
../src/core/Media.cpp:363:74: warning: 'void VlcMedia::parsedChanged(int)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         emit core->parsedChanged(event->u.media_parsed_changed.new_status);
                                                                          ^
In file included from ../src/core/Media.cpp:26:
../src/core/Media.h:321:28: note: declared here
     Q_DECL_DEPRECATED void parsedChanged(int status);
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[25/88] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/VideoMemoryStream.cpp.obj
../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.cpp:27:56: warning: 'VlcVideoMemoryStream' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 static inline VlcVideoMemoryStream *p_this(void *opaque) { return static_cast<VlcVideoMemoryStream *>(opaque); }
                                                        ^
In file included from ../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.cpp:25:
../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.h:55:43: note: declared here
 class Q_DECL_DEPRECATED VLCQT_CORE_EXPORT VlcVideoMemoryStream
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.cpp: In function 'VlcVideoMemoryStream* p_this(void*)':
../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.cpp:27:100: warning: 'VlcVideoMemoryStream' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 static inline VlcVideoMemoryStream *p_this(void *opaque) { return static_cast<VlcVideoMemoryStream *>(opaque); }
                                                                                                    ^
In file included from ../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.cpp:25:
../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.h:55:43: note: declared here
 class Q_DECL_DEPRECATED VLCQT_CORE_EXPORT VlcVideoMemoryStream
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.cpp: At global scope:
../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.cpp:28:57: warning: 'VlcVideoMemoryStream' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 static inline VlcVideoMemoryStream *p_this(void **opaque) { return static_cast<VlcVideoMemoryStream *>(*opaque); }
                                                         ^
In file included from ../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.cpp:25:
../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.h:55:43: note: declared here
 class Q_DECL_DEPRECATED VLCQT_CORE_EXPORT VlcVideoMemoryStream
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.cpp: In function 'VlcVideoMemoryStream* p_this(void**)':
../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.cpp:28:101: warning: 'VlcVideoMemoryStream' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 static inline VlcVideoMemoryStream *p_this(void **opaque) { return static_cast<VlcVideoMemoryStream *>(*opaque); }
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from ../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.cpp:25:
../src/core/VideoMemoryStream.h:55:43: note: declared here
 class Q_DECL_DEPRECATED VLCQT_CORE_EXPORT VlcVideoMemoryStream
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[26/88] Linking CXX shared library src\core\libVLCQtCored.dll
FAILED: src/core/libVLCQtCored.dll src/core/libVLCQtCored.dll.a
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Strawberry\c\bin\c++.exe -g -Wall -Wextra  -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -shared -o src\core\libVLCQtCored.dll -Wl,--out-implib,src\core\libVLCQtCored.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,1,--minor-image-version,2 src/core/VLCQtCore.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Core_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/AbstractVideoFrame.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/AbstractVideoStream.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Audio.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Common.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Enums.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Error.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Instance.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Media.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MediaList.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MediaListPlayer.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MediaPlayer.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MetaManager.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/ModuleDescription.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/TrackModel.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Video.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/VideoStream.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/YUVVideoFrame.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/VideoFrame.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/VideoMemoryStream.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Equalizer.cpp.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/compat/asprintf.c.obj src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/compat/vasprintf.c.obj  C:/Qt/Qt5.12.3/5.12.3/msvc2017_64/lib/Qt5Cored.lib  C:/vlc-3.0.16/sdk/lib/libvlc.lib  C:/vlc-3.0.16/sdk/lib/libvlccore.lib  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Core_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj: in function `VlcAudio::metaObject() const':
C:\vlc-qt\build/src/core/Core_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/moc_Audio.cpp:153: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK11QObjectData17dynamicMetaObjectEv'
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Core_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj: in function `VlcAudio::qt_metacast(char const*)':
C:\vlc-qt\build/src/core/Core_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/moc_Audio.cpp:161: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN7QObject11qt_metacastEPKc'
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: src/core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Core_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj: in function `VlcAudio::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)':
C:\vlc-qt\build/src/core/Core_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/moc_Audio.cpp:166: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN7QObject11qt_metacallEN11QMetaObject4CallEiPPv'
```

Comment: You are trying to link your stuff compiled with MinGW to a Qt 5.12.3 that was built with Microsoft Visual C++. This won't work. You need to get a Qt build for MinGW or need to build Qt from sources with MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to [@vre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5251059/vre) i figure it out.

**The solution :**

1. Download vlc-qt and vlc 3.0.16 and extract.
2. Open cmake-gui choose your visual studio and check "Specify native compilers".
   [image: Specify native compilers]
3. Set compilers to the correct MSVC like in the image
   [image: correct MSVC]
4. Add entries.. or just click "Configure" and fill it like in the image
   [image: entries]
5. After you fill all the entries and there no errors click "Generate"
6. Click "Open Project" to open it via Visual Studio and Build ..